# Promega 2 keyboard boot problem

Tags: digital-piano, repair

I have a GEM Promega 2 that has been a dream to use for the past few years, up until a couple days ago.  The problem seems to be that when I turn the unit on from the switch in the back, the character LED display shows a full solid bar.  The standby button lights up but none of the others on the main panel do.

It's a theory of mine that I may have disrupted the boot up at one point and the software may be corrupt.  I've tried several variations of trying to do a 'hard reset', but nothing up to this point seems to work.  I've also opened up the unit to see if there was anything obviously serviceable from the inside.

I've also found that trying to find a service manual rather challenging, coming up empty handed in the end.  Any reference material, or ideas on how to service or fix the unit would be greatly appreciated.

Life's suddenly very bland without a piano to play.

Comment: Google says "To hard reset the instrument turn on the main power switch on the back of the instrument while pressing and holding the standby button." …although another says "Hard reset: Hold Performance Edit while powering up.

Diagnostics: Hold down Sounds button while powering up. Use Sounds button to step thru tests."

Comment: I also found reference to being able to reinstall the OS - however, it apparently needs specific hardware … & runs on Win98 ;)

Comment: Tetsujin, thank you for your swift response and input.  I'm aware of these options and have tried a few times to hard reset with the main power and standby button, and I should have been more clear about that, sorry.  There isn't a Performance Edit button on this model to speak of I'm afraid, though it hasn't stopped me from trying with other button combinations, to no avail.

Comment: Tetsujin, is there a link to this reference by chance?

Comment: It's all just in chatroom type user-user helplines. That's pretty much all it said. You could try a new battery & see what happens.

Comment: Once again, Tetsujin, I greatly appreciate your feedback.  I'm going through the motions right now to try and find a battery, and at the same time, trying to unplug and replug in various things to see if it makes a difference if any.

Comment: I wish you luck. idk that particular keyboard, but you have my sympathies, as an owner of various long-in-the-tooth keyboards in varying stages of alzheimer's :\